# Term to distinguish "default" vs "made-up" classes in OOP

Tags: java, oop, language-agnostic

arraylists, buffered reader, scanner, etc.. all "Default" classes that "already exist" in the language..

unlike, say, public class widthOfTable which would be a "made up" class , that " did not already exist in language"..

why is there no term to distinguish these ideas when teaching? I barely discovered this difference in college , despite being here 3 years.

Comment: very innocent question. :)

Comment: The "default" classes you mention are in the JDK. The custom ones you make are not.

Comment: There is no _Default_ classes. There is the JDK which is a library like any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there is a pretty strong distinction between what you called "default" and "made-up" classes, which has to do with their package names.

All "default" classes are in some `java.*` package (`java.lang`, `java.util`, etc.), and no "made up" class could use a package name that starts with `java.`.

---

As for the fact that this distinction is blurred "when teaching", my feeling is that it's intentional. Java as a language is pretty much a set of keywords and syntax rules plus a `java.lang.Object` class that nobody could avoid extending (and which uses a few other built-in types like `String`, `Integer` and some exceptions).

The JDK is a Java library to help you with the most common use-cases, but in some cases there are better alternatives.

In my opinion, it would be a mistake to teach someone that `java.util.Calendar` or the `java.util.logging` stuff have any advantage over JodaTime or SLF4J just because they're in the classpath by default.

Comment: +1 was not aware of this fact. Tested it gives `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.test.code` but its not a compile time error.

Comment: @sakura: The same restriction applies to `javax.`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: @sakura: Since it's a security concern, it would be useless to rely on the compiler. Otherwise, I could provide the byte code for "my version of" `java.lang.String` in a jar library that you could "safely" run on your machine :). But I do agree the compiler could raise at least a warning...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question in my mind before and i had a different term for your word **default** and I called them **built-in** classes.

> why is **there no term** to distinguish these ideas when teaching?

there is already but **taught indirectly using the terms packages and namespaces**

if there is a time that you will design a programminng language you can tell any developer what are those default or built classes by putting them in right packages and namespaces for example

```
mydefaultclasses.io.print
mydefaultclasses.io.read
```

in java its really understandable that any classes under `java` namespace is a default or built-in class. it really depends upon what will came up on the documentation of the language you are trying to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Not sue if I totally understand your question, but you can find all the predefined classes in Java under the Java Class Library: [Java Class Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is more powerful to have packages or namespaces. Your way of thinking is like an implementation that only supports two namespaces. The standard library (in this case the java.*, in c++ std) is one, the other is all your other stuff. After a while, you probably end up with a new set of "default" classes anyway and you put those in a package to avoid clutter your global namespace.